# Invalid template file in a payment gateway

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, exception

I installed a payment gateway extension, and when placing an order with that specific payment gateway. I cannot view the order in the admin panel, when I click on the order number to view it, I get the following error.

```
1 exception(s):Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Gateway_Tap::info/tap.phtml' in module: 'Gateway_Tap' block's name: 'info\tap_0'
```

The template code from view/frontend/templates/info

```
<dl class="payment-method gateway">
<dt class="title"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?></dt>
<dt class="title"">
<?php 
    /* $params = $block->getRequest()->getParams(); 
    if ($block->getChargeId($params['order_id'])) {
        echo "Tap ID: ".$block->getChargeId($params['order_id'])."<br>";
        echo  "Card Number: " . str_repeat('*' , 12) .$block->getLastFourDigits($params['order_id'])."<br>";
        echo "Payment type:  ". $block->getPaymentType($params['order_id'])."<br>";
    } */
?>
</dt>
```

Thank you

Comment: could you please add xml code and phtml path in question?

Answer (score 0):

Create the .phtml file inside the adminhtml folder